# Xcode submit to app store issue

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store

I'm trying to upload a new version of my app, but got error.
[image]

But if i select only "Validate..." button, it's ok :(
[image]

Up to this point everything was good and application was stored successfully.

Comment: Did you create a new version of your app in itunes connect with the same version number ?

Comment: No. I use new version.

Comment: You need to create a new version in itunes connect first with the same version number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason of that error but got an alternative. Export the .ipa file and try uploading it via the Application Loader (Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader)